# Crash in Destructor in C++11, after shared pointer goes out of scope

Tags: c++11, memory-leaks, gdb, valgrind, shared-ptr

I am facing crash in Destructor. Below is the code snippet of Object creation of carrier and destructor of object once erase from map is

Here is the Code Snippet

/* Object Creation */

```
shared_ptr<ICarrier> Factory::MakeCarrier(int carrierId, int beamId)
{
    return make_shared < Carrier > (carrierId, beamId);
}
```

/* Dest */

```
shared_ptr<ICarrier> pCarrier = nullptr;

for (auto carrierIterator = mCarrierIdToCarrierMap.cbegin();
    carrierIterator != mCarrierIdToCarrierMap.cend();)
{
    carrierIterator = mCarrierIdToCarrierMap.erase(carrierIterator);
}

virtual ~ICarrier()
{
}

Carrier::Carrier(int carrierId, int beamId)
{
    // Create new logger level by appending beam ID.
    string newLoggerLevel = "rgw.beam." + to_string(beamId) + ".carrier."+ to_string(carrierId);
    // Retrieve logger for the newly created logger level
    mLogger = log4cxx::Logger::getLogger(newLoggerLevel);
    LOG4CXX_INFO(mLogger, " Carrier created with Id :" << carrierId);
    mPmcIp = 0;
}

Carrier::~Carrier()
{
}
```

GDB o/p

```
Breakpoint 2, Carrier::~Carrier (this=0xccc478, __in_chrg=<value optimized out>) at Carrier.cpp:24

    24      Carrier::~Carrier()

    (gdb) bt

    #0  Carrier::~Carrier (this=0xccc478, __in_chrg=<value optimized out>) at Carrier.cpp:24

    #1  0x00000000004469de in Carrier::~Carrier (this=0xccc478, __in_chrg=<value optimized out>) at Carrier.cpp:27

    #2  0x0000000000422f5d in __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<Carrier>::destroy<Carrier> (this=0xccc470, __p=0xccc478) at /usr/local/tools/gcc/4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/ext/new_allocator.h:124

    #3  0x0000000000422e21 in std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<Carrier> >::_S_destroy<Carrier> (__a=..., __p=0xccc478) at /usr/local/tools/gcc/4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/alloc_traits.h:281

    #4  0x0000000000422cf9 in std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<Carrier> >::destroy<Carrier> (__a=..., __p=0xccc478) at /usr/local/tools/gcc/4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/alloc_traits.h:405

    #5  0x0000000000422a81 in std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<Carrier, std::allocator<Carrier>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_dispose (this=0xccc460) at /usr/local/tools/gcc/4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:407

    #6  0x000000000040aee0 in std::_Sp_counted_base<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_release (this=0xccc460) at /usr/local/tools/gcc/4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:144

    #7  0x000000000040acd0 in std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::operator= (this=0x7ffffffe25f8, __r=...) at /usr/local/tools/gcc/4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:565

    #8  0x0000000000419f27 in std::__shared_ptr<ICarrier, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::operator= (this=0x7ffffffe25f0) at /usr/local/tools/gcc/4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:728

    #9  0x0000000000419f51 in std::shared_ptr<ICarrier>::operator= (this=0x7ffffffe25f0) at /usr/local/tools/gcc/4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/shared_ptr.h:93

    #10 0x00000000004154c6 in Beam::DeleteAllCarriers (this=0xccca58) at Beam.cpp:383

    #11 0x00000000004151eb in Beam::OnDeleting (this=0xccca58, tlliBvciVector=...) at Beam.cpp:352

    #12 0x0000000000428134 in PBSC::DeleteBeamsWithTraversedFlagSet (this=0xcc8080) at PBSC.cpp:587

    #13 0x0000000000428ceb in PBSC::OnCarrierMapping (this=0xcc8080, pCarrierMapping=...) at PBSC.cpp:682

    #14 0x0000000000409615 in pbsc::RMS::HandleRMSCarrierMappingMsg (this=0xccb970, recvdCarrierMapping=...) at RMS.cpp:133

    #15 0x0000000000408f10 in pbsc::RMS::HandleMessage (this=0xccb970, portNumber=21015, pRecvMsg=0x7ffffffea470 "\n\002\b\003\f\003\204", sizeOfMessageRead=4) at RMS.cpp:55

    #16 0x0000000000481630 in inframe::ModuleManager::ProcessRxMessage (this=0xcc9280, msgBuf=0x7ffffffea470 "\n\002\b\003\f\003\204", numOfBytes=@0x7fffffff9ea8, portNumber=@0x7ffffffe69c4, remoteAddr=...) at ModuleManager.cpp:1054

    #17 0x000000000047fdb0 in inframe::ModuleManager::RecvAndForwardMessage (this=0xcc9280, portNumber=21015) at ModuleManager.cpp:612

    #18 0x0000000000451f9f in pbsc::PBSCApp::ActOnInterrupt (this=0x7fffffffdb90, tick=83118159) at PBSCApp.cpp:101

    #19 0x00000000004798a1 in inframe::AppTask::ReadInterrupt (this=0x7fffffffdb90) at AppTask.cpp:263

    #20 0x0000000000455d60 in pbsc::PBSCAppMain (argc=7, argv=0x7fffffffe1c8) at PBSCApp.cpp:699

    #21 0x00000000004550b4 in main (argc=7, argv=0x7fffffffe1c8) at PBSCApp.cpp:550

    (gdb) n
```

Crash:

*** glibc detected *** /home/nverma/Test/PBSC_1/bin/pbsc_1: free(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000000ccc478 ***

```
 Backtrace:

/lib64/libc.so.6[0x3cb1c76166]

/home/nverma/Test/PBSC_1/bin/pbsc_1[0x4469ea]

/home/nverma/Test/PBSC_1/bin/pbsc_1[0x422f5d]

/home/nverma/Test/PBSC_1/bin/pbsc_1[0x422e21]

/home/nverma/Test/PBSC_1/bin/pbsc_1[0x422cf9]

/home/nverma/Test/PBSC_1/bin/pbsc_1[0x422a81]

/home/nverma/Test/PBSC_1/bin/pbsc_1[0x40aee0]

/home/nverma/Test/PBSC_1/bin/pbsc_1[0x40acd0]

/home/nverma/Test/PBSC_1/bin/pbsc_1[0x419f27]

/home/nverma/Test/PBSC_1/bin/pbsc_1[0x419f51]

/home/nverma/Test/PBSC_1/bin/pbsc_1[0x4154c6]

/home/nverma/Test/PBSC_1/bin/pbsc_1[0x4151eb]

/home/nverma/Test/PBSC_1/bin/pbsc_1[0x428134]

/home/nverma/Test/PBSC_1/bin/pbsc_1[0x428ceb]

/home/nverma/Test/PBSC_1/bin/pbsc_1[0x409615]

/home/nverma/Test/PBSC_1/bin/pbsc_1[0x408f10]

/home/nverma/Test/PBSC_1/bin/pbsc_1[0x481630]

/home/nverma/Test/PBSC_1/bin/pbsc_1[0x47fdb0]

/home/nverma/Test/PBSC_1/bin/pbsc_1[0x451f9f]

/home/nverma/Test/PBSC_1/bin/pbsc_1[0x4798a1]

/home/nverma/Test/PBSC_1/bin/pbsc_1[0x455d60]

/home/nverma/Test/PBSC_1/bin/pbsc_1[0x4550b4]

/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd)[0x3cb1c1ed1d]

/home/nverma/Test/PBSC_1/bin/pbsc_1[0x408489]

======= Memory map: ========

00400000-005f8000 r-xp 00000000 fd:02 540387                             /home/nverma/Test/PBSC_1/bin/pbsc_1

007f8000-007f9000 rw-p 001f8000 fd:02 540387                             /home/nverma/Test/PBSC_1/bin/pbsc_1

007f9000-00cd7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]

33a0800000-33a081d000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 1310819                        /lib64/libselinux.so.1

33a081d000-33a0a1c000 ---p 0001d000 fd:00 1310819                        /lib64/libselinux.so.1

33a0a1c000-33a0a1d000 r--p 0001c000 fd:00 1310819                        /lib64/libselinux.so.1

33a0a1d000-33a0a1e000 rw-p 0001d000 fd:00 1310819                        /lib64/libselinux.so.1

33a0a1e000-33a0a1f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0

33a5c00000-33a5c04000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 1327246                        /lib64/libuuid.so.1.3.0

33a5c04000-33a5e03000 ---p 00004000 fd:00 1327246                        /lib64/libuuid.so.1.3.0

33a5e03000-33a5e04000 rw-p 00003000 fd:00 1327246                        /lib64/libuuid.so.1.3.0

33a6000000-33a6027000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 2756506                        /usr/lib64/libssh2.so.1.0.1

33a6027000-33a6226000 ---p 00027000 fd:00 2756506                        /usr/lib64/libssh2.so.1.0.1

33a6226000-33a6227000 rw-p 00026000 fd:00 2756506                        /usr/lib64/libssh2.so.1.0.1

33a6227000-33a6228000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0

33a6400000-33a6403000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 1327243                        /lib64/libcom_err.so.2.1

33a6403000-33a6602000 ---p 00003000 fd:00 1327243                        /lib64/libcom_err.so.2.1

33a6602000-33a6603000 r--p 00002000 fd:00 1327243                        /lib64/libcom_err.so.2.1

33a6603000-33a6604000 rw-p 00003000 fd:00 1327243                        /lib64/libcom_err.so.2.1

33a6800000-33a680a000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 1310815                        /lib64/libkrb5support.so.0.1

33a680a000-33a6a09000 ---p 0000a000 fd:00 1310815                        /lib64/libkrb5support.so.0.1

33a6a09000-33a6a0a000 r--p 00009000 fd:00 1310815                        /lib64/libkrb5support.so.0.1

33a6a0a000-33a6a0b000 rw-p 0000a000 fd:00 1310815                        /lib64/libkrb5support.so.0.1

33a6c00000-33a6c29000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 1327242                        /lib64/libk5crypto.so.3.1

33a6c29000-33a6e29000 ---p 00029000 fd:00 1327242                        /lib64/libk5crypto.so.3.1

33a6e29000-33a6e2a000 r--p 00029000 fd:00 1327242                        /lib64/libk5crypto.so.3.1

33a6e2a000-33a6e2b000 rw-p 0002a000 fd:00 1327242                        /lib64/libk5crypto.so.3.1

33a6e2b000-33a6e2c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0

33a7000000-33a70db000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 1327244                        /lib64/libkrb5.so.3.3

33a70db000-33a72da000 ---p 000db000 fd:00 1327244                        /lib64/libkrb5.so.3.3

33a72da000-33a72e4000 r--p 000da000 fd:00 1327244                        /lib64/libkrb5.so.3.3

33a72e4000-33a72e6000 rw-p 000e4000 fd:00 1327244                        /lib64/libkrb5.so.3.3

33a7400000-33a7441000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 1327245                        /lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2.2

33a7441000-33a7641000 ---p 00041000 fd:00 1327245                        /lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2.2

33a7641000-33a7642000 r--p 00041000 fd:00 1327245                        /lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2.2

33a7642000-33a7644000 rw-p 00042000 fd:00 1327245                        /lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2.2

33a7800000-33a7861000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 2764023                        /usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.1e

33a7861000-33a7a60000 ---p 00061000 fd:00 2764023                        /usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.1e

33a7a60000-33a7a64000 r--p 00060000 fd:00 2764023                        /usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.1e

33a7a64000-33a7a6b000 rw-p 00064000 fd:00 2764023                        /usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.1e

33a8800000-33a8851000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 2767573                        /usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4.1.1

33a8851000-33a8a50000 ---p 00051000 fd:00 2767573                        /usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4.1.1

33a8a50000-33a8a53000 rw-p 00050000 fd:00 2767573                        /usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4.1.1

3585000000-35851b5000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 2761539                        /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.1e

35851b5000-35853b5000 ---p 001b5000 fd:00 2761539                        /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.1e

35853b5000-35853d0000 r--p 001b5000 fd:00 2761539                        /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.1e

35853d0000-35853dc000 rw-p 001d0000 fd:00 2761539                        /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.1e

35853dc000-35853e0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0

3cb1800000-3cb1820000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 1327173                        /lib64/ld-2.12.so

3cb1a1f000-3cb1a20000 r--p 0001f000 fd:00 1327173                        /lib64/ld-2.12.so

3cb1a20000-3cb1a21000 rw-p 00020000 fd:00 1327173                        /lib64/ld-2.12.so

3cb1a21000-3cb1a22000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0

3cb1c00000-3cb1d8b000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 1327174                        /lib64/libc-2.12.so

3cb1d8b000-3cb1f8a000 ---p 0018b000 fd:00 1327174                        /lib64/libc-2.12.so

3cb1f8a000-3cb1f8e000 r--p 0018a000 fd:00 1327174                        /lib64/libc-2.12.so

3cb1f8e000-3cb1f8f000 rw-p 0018e000 fd:00 1327174                        /lib64/libc-2.12.so
```

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.

0x0000003cb1c32925 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6

```
(gdb) bt

#0  0x0000003cb1c32925 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6

#1  0x0000003cb1c34105 in abort () from /lib64/libc.so.6

#2  0x0000003cb1c70837 in __libc_message () from /lib64/libc.so.6

#3  0x0000003cb1c76166 in malloc_printerr () from /lib64/libc.so.6

#4  0x00000000004469ea in Carrier::~Carrier (this=0xccc478, __in_chrg=<value optimized out>) at Carrier.cpp:27

#5  0x0000000000422f5d in __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<Carrier>::destroy<Carrier> (this=0xccc470, __p=0xccc478) at /usr/local/tools/gcc/4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/ext/new_allocator.h:124

#6  0x0000000000422e21 in std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<Carrier> >::_S_destroy<Carrier> (__a=..., __p=0xccc478) at /usr/local/tools/gcc/4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/alloc_traits.h:281

#7  0x0000000000422cf9 in std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<Carrier> >::destroy<Carrier> (__a=..., __p=0xccc478) at /usr/local/tools/gcc/4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/alloc_traits.h:405

#8  0x0000000000422a81 in std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<Carrier, std::allocator<Carrier>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_dispose (this=0xccc460) at /usr/local/tools/gcc/4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:407

#9  0x000000000040aee0 in std::_Sp_counted_base<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_release (this=0xccc460) at /usr/local/tools/gcc/4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:144

#10 0x000000000040acd0 in std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::operator= (this=0x7ffffffe25f8, __r=...) at /usr/local/tools/gcc/4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:565

#11 0x0000000000419f27 in std::__shared_ptr<ICarrier, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::operator= (this=0x7ffffffe25f0) at /usr/local/tools/gcc/4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:728

#12 0x0000000000419f51 in std::shared_ptr<ICarrier>::operator= (this=0x7ffffffe25f0) at /usr/local/tools/gcc/4.8.2/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/shared_ptr.h:93

#13 0x00000000004154c6 in Beam::DeleteAllCarriers (this=0xccca58) at Beam.cpp:383

#14 0x00000000004151eb in Beam::OnDeleting (this=0xccca58, tlliBvciVector=...) at Beam.cpp:352

#15 0x0000000000428134 in PBSC::DeleteBeamsWithTraversedFlagSet (this=0xcc8080) at PBSC.cpp:587

#16 0x0000000000428ceb in PBSC::OnCarrierMapping (this=0xcc8080, pCarrierMapping=...) at PBSC.cpp:682

#17 0x0000000000409615 in pbsc::RMS::HandleRMSCarrierMappingMsg (this=0xccb970, recvdCarrierMapping=...) at RMS.cpp:133

#18 0x0000000000408f10 in pbsc::RMS::HandleMessage (this=0xccb970, portNumber=21015, pRecvMsg=0x7ffffffea470 "\n\002\b\003\f\003\204", sizeOfMessageRead=4) at RMS.cpp:55

#19 0x0000000000481630 in inframe::ModuleManager::ProcessRxMessage (this=0xcc9280, msgBuf=0x7ffffffea470 "\n\002\b\003\f\003\204", numOfBytes=@0x7fffffff9ea8, portNumber=@0x7ffffffe69c4, remoteAddr=...) at ModuleManager.cpp:1054

#20 0x000000000047fdb0 in inframe::ModuleManager::RecvAndForwardMessage (this=0xcc9280, portNumber=21015) at ModuleManager.cpp:612

#21 0x0000000000451f9f in pbsc::PBSCApp::ActOnInterrupt (this=0x7fffffffdb90, tick=83118159) at PBSCApp.cpp:101

#22 0x00000000004798a1 in inframe::AppTask::ReadInterrupt (this=0x7fffffffdb90) at AppTask.cpp:263

#23 0x0000000000455d60 in pbsc::PBSCAppMain (argc=7, argv=0x7fffffffe1c8) at PBSCApp.cpp:699

#24 0x00000000004550b4 in main (argc=7, argv=0x7fffffffe1c8) at PBSCApp.cpp:550
```

Valgrind

```
==32508== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==32508== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==32508== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==32508== Command: ./pbsc_1 1 3145740 3178509 193 45.48.25.21 1

==32508== Syscall param socketcall.recvfrom(fromlen_in) points to uninitialised byte(s)
==32508==    at 0x3CB280EBD3: ??? (in /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so)
==32508==    by 0x479B18: inframe::AppTask::ReadInterrupt() (AppTask.cpp:234)
==32508==    by 0x45617F: pbsc::PBSCAppMain(int, char**) (PBSCApp.cpp:699)
==32508==    by 0x4554D3: main (PBSCApp.cpp:550)
==32508==  Address 0x7fefff99c is on thread 1's stack
==32508==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==32508==    at 0x479AA0: inframe::AppTask::ReadInterrupt() (AppTask.cpp:216)

==32508== 
==32508== Syscall param socketcall.sendto(msg) points to uninitialised byte(s)
==32508==    at 0x3CB280EDB3: ??? (in /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so)
==32508==    by 0x482301: inframe::Module::SendMessage(std::string const*, int) (Module.cpp:94)
==32508==    by 0x40E272: pbsc::EMS::SendEMSCompStatusMsg(CompUnicastMetaMessage&) (EMS.cpp:378)
==32508==    by 0x429BF9: PBSC::SendEMSComponentStatusMessage() const (PBSC.cpp:800)
==32508==    by 0x4244EF: PBSC::OnSgsnStatusChange(ESgsnStatus) (PBSC.cpp:130)
==32508==    by 0x432FCC: SGSN::DecodeMessageFromStack(char*) (SGSN.cpp:447)
==32508==    by 0x43703C: SGSN::HandleMessage(unsigned short, char const*, int) (SGSN.cpp:810)
==32508==    by 0x481A4F: inframe::ModuleManager::ProcessRxMessage(char*, int&, unsigned short&, sockaddr_in&) (ModuleManager.cpp:1054)
==32508==    by 0x4801CF: inframe::ModuleManager::RecvAndForwardMessage(unsigned short) (ModuleManager.cpp:612)
==32508==    by 0x4523E0: pbsc::PBSCApp::ActOnInterrupt(unsigned long) (PBSCApp.cpp:102)
==32508==    by 0x479CC0: inframe::AppTask::ReadInterrupt() (AppTask.cpp:263)
==32508==    by 0x45617F: pbsc::PBSCAppMain(int, char**) (PBSCApp.cpp:699)
==32508==  Address 0x5fc4baa is 170 bytes inside a block of size 176 alloc'd
==32508==    at 0x4A075BC: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:298)
==32508==    by 0x5813CA8: std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned long, unsigned long, std::allocator<char> const&) (new_allocator.h:104)
==32508==    by 0x581487A: std::string::_Rep::_M_clone(std::allocator<char> const&, unsigned long) (basic_string.tcc:629)
==32508==    by 0x5814913: std::string::reserve(unsigned long) (basic_string.tcc:510)
==32508==    by 0x5814CD5: std::string::append(unsigned long, char) (basic_string.tcc:288)
==32508==    by 0x4C6455E: google::protobuf::MessageLite::AppendPartialToString(std::string*) const (basic_string.h:667)
==32508==    by 0x40E172: pbsc::EMS::SendEMSCompStatusMsg(CompUnicastMetaMessage&) (EMS.cpp:375)
==32508==    by 0x429BF9: PBSC::SendEMSComponentStatusMessage() const (PBSC.cpp:800)
==32508==    by 0x4244EF: PBSC::OnSgsnStatusChange(ESgsnStatus) (PBSC.cpp:130)
==32508==    by 0x432FCC: SGSN::DecodeMessageFromStack(char*) (SGSN.cpp:447)
==32508==    by 0x43703C: SGSN::HandleMessage(unsigned short, char const*, int) (SGSN.cpp:810)
==32508==    by 0x481A4F: inframe::ModuleManager::ProcessRxMessage(char*, int&, unsigned short&, sockaddr_in&) (ModuleManager.cpp:1054)
==32508==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==32508==    at 0x4A075BC: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:298)
==32508==    by 0x411E42: pbsc::EMSManager::CreateModule() const (EMSManager.cpp:67)
==32508==    by 0x47E386: inframe::ModuleManager::Associate(unsigned int) (ModuleManager.cpp:133)
==32508==    by 0x45281B: pbsc::PBSCApp::InitializeEMSManager(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned short) const (PBSCApp.cpp:164)
==32508==    by 0x455FC3: pbsc::PBSCAppMain(int, char**) (PBSCApp.cpp:675)
==32508==    by 0x4554D3: main (PBSCApp.cpp:550)
==32508== 

==32508== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==32508==    at 0x4A05FD6: operator delete(void*) (vg_replace_malloc.c:480)
==32508==    by 0x446E07: Carrier::~Carrier() (Carrier.cpp:33)
==32508==    by 0x4231D0: void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<Carrier>::destroy<Carrier>(Carrier*) (new_allocator.h:124)
==32508==    by 0x423094: std::enable_if<std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<Carrier> >::__destroy_helper<Carrier>::value, void>::type std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<Carrier> >::_S_destroy<Carrier>(std::allocator<Carrier>&, Carrier*) (alloc_traits.h:281)
==32508==    by 0x422F6C: void std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<Carrier> >::destroy<Carrier>(std::allocator<Carrier>&, Carrier*) (alloc_traits.h:405)
==32508==    by 0x422CF4: std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<Carrier, std::allocator<Carrier>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_dispose() (shared_ptr_base.h:407)
==32508==    by 0x40B04F: std::_Sp_counted_base<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_release() (shared_ptr_base.h:144)
==32508==    by 0x40AE3F: std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::operator=(std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> const&) (shared_ptr_base.h:565)
==32508==    by 0x41A154: std::__shared_ptr<ICarrier, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::operator=(std::__shared_ptr<ICarrier, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> const&) (shared_ptr_base.h:728)
==32508==    by 0x41A17E: std::shared_ptr<ICarrier>::operator=(std::shared_ptr<ICarrier> const&) (shared_ptr.h:93)
==32508==    by 0x4156A0: Beam::DeleteAllCarriers() (Beam.cpp:386)
==32508==    by 0x4153C2: Beam::OnDeleting(std::vector<std::pair<int, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, int> > >&) (Beam.cpp:355)
==32508==  Address 0x5fe21a8 is 24 bytes inside a block of size 64 alloc'd
==32508==    at 0x4A075BC: operator new(unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:298)
==32508==    by 0x421995: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<Carrier, std::allocator<Carrier>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >::allocate(unsigned long, void const*) (new_allocator.h:104)
==32508==    by 0x4215D9: std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<Carrier, std::allocator<Carrier>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> > >::allocate(std::allocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<Carrier, std::allocator<Carrier>, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> >&, unsigned long) (alloc_traits.h:351)
==32508==    by 0x4211AF: std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_count<Carrier, std::allocator<Carrier>, int&, int&>(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, Carrier*, std::allocator<Carrier> const&, int&, int&) (shared_ptr_base.h:499)
==32508==    by 0x420DDA: std::__shared_ptr<Carrier, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::__shared_ptr<std::allocator<Carrier>, int&, int&>(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, std::allocator<Carrier> const&, int&, int&) (shared_ptr_base.h:957)
==32508==    by 0x420B97: std::shared_ptr<Carrier>::shared_ptr<std::allocator<Carrier>, int&, int&>(std::_Sp_make_shared_tag, std::allocator<Carrier> const&, int&, int&) (shared_ptr.h:316)
==32508==    by 0x4208B5: std::shared_ptr<Carrier> std::allocate_shared<Carrier, std::allocator<Carrier>, int&, int&>(std::allocator<Carrier> const&, int&, int&) (shared_ptr.h:598)
==32508==    by 0x420576: _ZSt11make_sharedI7CarrierIRiS1_EESt10shared_ptrIT_EDpOT0_ (shared_ptr.h:614)
==32508==    by 0x4200FE: Factory::MakeCarrier(int, int) (Factory.cpp:43)
==32508==    by 0x415178: Beam::AddCarrier(int, int) (Beam.cpp:318)
==32508==    by 0x414FB4: Beam::Update(rgw::common::BeamInfo const&, std::vector<std::pair<int, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, int> > >&) (Beam.cpp:294)
==32508==    by 0x428D91: PBSC::OnCarrierMapping(rgw::common::CarrierMapping const&) (PBSC.cpp:662)
==32508==
```

Comment: Try valgrind.  And/or post some code we can actually run.

Comment: What is the relationship between ICarrier and Carrier? Need more code to debug.

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, but it would be faster and simpler to empty `mCarrierIdToCarrierMap` with [`clear`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/clear) than by erasing elements one-at-a-time in that `for` loop.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I have added valgrind output also.

Comment: @Garland ICarrier is interface to Carrier.

Comment: @Casey I tried that too, even without that also, then also i am having crash at same point.

Comment: Can we see the constructors and destructors for Carrier?

Comment: Also the destructor for ICarrier... is it `virtual`?

Comment: @AndyG Addeed all Constructor and Destructors code. pls chk. Thanks

Comment: Found Bug. Sorry but one macro is causing problem that is locally defined. When object is instantiated at that time Macro is not defined, but at the time of deletion of object that is defined. Just fix that macro issue and everything works well then.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all the destructors, none appear to be needed.